# Display a different background after the load during 5 seconds and then change it definitively

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to display in the first 5 seconds after loading, a different background every 1 second or a little less. And after these 5 seconds I would like to set a definite background.

I set already the class of my div:

```
<div id="plateau" class="step01">
<div id="plateau-fond">
```

And I set the background in my CSS:

```
#plateau.step-01 #plateau-fond
 {
  background-image:url('../img/plateau-03-step-01.png');
 }
```

I would like to use javascript or jQuery to execute as mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

Of the top of my head, I'd suggest something like the following:

```
$(function() {
  var step = 1;

  var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
     var $plateau = $("#plateau");
     $plateau.removeClass("step0" + step);
     step++;
     $plateau.addClass("step0" + step);
     if(step == 5) { 
         window.clearInterval(interval);
     }
  }, 1000);
});
```

Going to verify this in a jsfiddle in a second.

Comment: may be $plateau.addClass("step0" +step) instead of $plateau.addClass("step0" +(++step)) because you have already increamented step++ in the previous line.

Comment: That's true ... fixed it. (Had the whole jQuery-manipulation as a one-liner but tried to make it more readable)

Comment: Oh, it's a good function. I used a setTimeout but setInterval it's preaty much good too.

But, in this function, during the 5 seconds, I want to display step02, then step01, then again step02 and again step01. Is this possible to do it dynamically? thanks again :-)

Comment: Sure. Just set the step to 0 in line two and change the "step" to "(step % 2 + 1)" in the addClass/removeClass calls. I've updated [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2cJRn/1/)

Comment: Thanks, but, in concret cases, my actual step can be 05 and my previous step can be 04.
So if I execute your coe with step05 in actual and step04 for previous, it doesn't work.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that should do the task you need
Stylesheet: You need to write your styles / image etc

```
<style type="text/css">
    .step00{background:#000000;}  /*this is the initial background when page loaded*/
.step01{background:#454545;}  /*First change after 1 sec*/
.step02{background:#333333;}  /*2nd change after 2 sec*/
.step03{background:#234567;}  /*3rd change after 3 sec*/
.step04{background:#789564;}  /*4th change after 5 sec*/
.step05{background:#cccccc;}  /*5th change after 5 sec*/
.stepfixed{background:#fff222;} /*final definitive bg after 6 sec*/
</style>
```

Html

```
<div id="plateau" class="step00">
<div id="plateau-fond">

<script type="text/javascript">
    var count = 0;
    jQuery(window).load(function () {
        var interval = window.setInterval("change_bg()",1000); //1000 = 1sec here
    });
    function change_bg() {
        jQuery('div#plateau').removeClass('step0'+count);
        count++;
        if(count > 5) {
            jQuery('div#plateau').addClass('stepfixed');
            window.clearInterval(interval);
        } else {
            jQuery('div#plateau').addClass('step0'+count);
        }
    }
</script>
```

***Jquery is required for the above code to work. Do not forget to include jquery. To include jquery is very simple. If you can not do this leave a comment.

Comment: i am sending you how, wait a minute

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
    .step00{background:#000000;}  /*this is the initial background when page loaded*/
.step01{background:#454545;}  /*First change after 1 sec*/
.step02{background:#333333;}  /*2nd change after 2 sec*/
.step03{background:#234567;}  /*3rd change after 3 sec*/
.step04{background:#789564;}  /*4th change after 5 sec*/
.step05{background:#cccccc;}  /*5th change after 5 sec*/
.stepfixed{background:#fff222;} /*final definitive bg after 6 sec*/
</style>

    <div id="plateau" class="step00">
    <div id="plateau-fond">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var count = 0;
        var flag = 1;
        jQuery(window).load(function () {
            var interval = window.setInterval("change_bg()",1000); //1000 = 1sec here
        });
        function change_bg() {
            if(count == 0)
                jQuery('div#plateau').removeClass('step00');
            else
                jQuery('div#plateau').removeClass('step0'+flag);
            count++;
            if(flag % 2 == 0)
                flag = 1;
            else
                flag = 2;
            if(count > 5) {
                jQuery('div#plateau').addClass('stepfixed');
                window.clearInterval(interval);
            } else {
                jQuery('div#plateau').addClass('step0'+flag);
            }
        }
    </script>
```